# Integrating $\int \frac{3}{x^2+12x+45}$

Tags: integration, rational-functions

My professor is giving a mastery exam over integrals and one of the sections covered is un-factorable quadratics like this problem that are supposed to be done by completing the square.

$$\int \frac{3}{x^2+12x+45}$$

Completing the square and everything gives $$\int \frac{3}{(x+6)^2+9}$$

I figured the answer would be somewhere in the range of $$\frac{1}{3} \tan^{-1}\Biggl(\frac{x+6}{9}\Biggl)+c$$

like I learned in the textbook aside from not knowing what to do with the three. Anyways the answer is somehow $$\tan^{-1}\Biggl(\frac{x}{3}+2\Biggl) + c$$ and I don't know what I did wrong

Comment: How did you go from your second to your third equation?  And what could "something in the range" possibly mean in symbolic math?

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone will be able to tell you what you did wrong without you explaining why you chose the answer you did.  In any case, one way to solve it is to first write the integrand as
$$\frac{3}{(x+6)^2+9} = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{\left(\frac{x+6}{3}\right)^2+1}$$
This second form may match your textbook's work a little closer.

Comment: I don't understand how 3 suddenly becomes $\frac{1}{3}$ I got this from a website not a book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use the formula
$$\int\frac{du}{u^2+a^2}=\frac{1}{a}\arctan\frac{u}{a}+C.$$
Now, we have $$\int\frac{3}{x^2+12x+45}dx=3\int\frac{dx}{(x+6)^2+9}.$$
With $a=3$ and $u=x+6$, you will get what you want.

Comment: okay perfect sense

Comment: @K. Gibson You're welcome

Answer (score 2):

Since\begin{align}\int\frac3{x^2+12x+45}\,\mathrm dx&=\int\frac3{(x+6)^2+9}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int\frac{\frac39}{\frac{(x+6)^2}9+1}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int\frac{\frac13}{\left(\frac{x+6}3\right)^2+1}\,\mathrm dx,\end{align}the substitution $y=\frac{x+6}3$ leads indeed to the answer $\arctan\left(\frac{x+6}3\right)$.

Comment: Can you go into further detail about step 2-3?

Comment: Do you mean the equality$$\int\frac3{(x+6)^2+9}\,\mathrm dx=\int\frac{\frac13}{\left(\frac{x+6}3\right)^2+1}\,\mathrm dx?$$

Comment: yes that would be it

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Answer (score 2):

You should have had $$\color{red}{3}\cdot\frac13\arctan\left(\frac{x+6}{\color{red}{3}}\right)+\text{some constant},$$ which indeed is $$\arctan{\left(\frac{x}{2} +2\right)}+\text{some constant}.$$

The correct formula is $$\int\frac{\mathrm d x}{(x+a)^2+b^2}=\frac1b\arctan\left(\frac{x+a}{b}\right)+\text{some constant}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(x+6)^2+9=9\Bigl((\frac x3 +2)^2+1\Bigr)$$

put $$t=\frac x 3+2$$
with $dx=3dt$,

the integral becomes

$$\int \frac{3.3dt}{9(t^2+1)}=\arctan(t)+C$$
$$=\arctan(\frac x3+2)+C$$

Comment: why on earth would you pull out a 9. I don't see how that is even neccessary

Comment: @K.Gibson I factor out by 9 to get someting like $$X^2+1$$

Comment: okay is there a way around that?

Comment: This is a classical classical method.